# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 'org.springframework.securityUserDetailsService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

It seems that Spring can't autowire the `UserDetailsService`. I don't understand why.

**WebConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("testproject")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "testproject",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
 public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
bean.setSuffix(".html");


        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()  {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService =
                new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
        return userDetailsService;
    }
}
```

**MyAppInitializer.java**:

```
public class MyAppInitializer extends
                AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("onStartup!");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        root.register(WebConfig.class);
        root.setServletContext(sc);

        root.scan("testproject");
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet =
                sc.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");
    }

        @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;


    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring();
    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
              //  .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
                    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Full error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
 No qualifying bean of type 
'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**:

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.java**:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService  {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException  {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            return new UserDetailsImpl(user);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really using Spring Boot because judging from the amount of config you are doing you aren't?

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using Spring MVC

Comment: I just removed the `spring-boot` tag.

Comment: Remove the bootstrapping of the `ContextLoaderListener` from the `MyAppInitializer` and add `WebConfig` to the `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` just as the `SecurityConfig`. Both load a `ContextLoaderLIstener` but only one will remain.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are a genius! It helped, no errors now! Thank you!

Comment: @M.Deinum May I ask you - how would you recommend going about learning all these configuration/low level details? Did you read Spring documentation to understand it so well?

Comment: I've been using Spring since about 2003, contributed and seen the rise of the different projects. I'm knee deep into the code basically (especially Spring, Spring Boot but Security, Batch hold also little secrets). Use it and read the documentation and I would suggest using Spring Boot nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@ComponentScan` should point to the package of the classes, I'm assuming `testproject` is not the package name.

Comment: `testproject` **is** the root package in `src/main/java` folder